# Why is my ICollection null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I established a relationshop One-To-Many between two entities.

And everytime I add a new record with its respective relationship, it isn't being mapped to the other entity with the collection.

This is my class Typology:

```
public class Typology
{     
    // Rest of fields removed...
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my other class (Project):

```
public class Project
{
    // Rest of fields removed...
    public Typology Typology { get; set; }
}
```

And I established the relationship through this way:

```
// This is my EntityTypeConfiguration for Project.
.HasRequired<Typology>(p => p.Typology)
.WithMany(t => t.Projects);
```

Everytime I need to create a Project, I do it like so:

```
Typology typology = dbContext.Typologies.Where(t => t.Id == projectDTO.TypologyId).First();
projectContext.Typology = typology;
```

And then I add and save changes like:

```
dbContext.Projects.Add(projectContext);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Now, since this is a One-To-Many Relationship and I add a Typology to my Project object, logically, the project should be added "behind the scenes" to the collection of that typology automatically.

Well, that isn't the case.

While debugging, I tried to get that typology like this:

```
Typology typology = dbContext.Typologies.Where(t => t.Id == id).First();
```

The result was that I got all the fields of that typology such as Id, Description, etc, BUT the collection of projects is null.

Comment: Is there `Projects  = new HashSet<Project>();` inside `Typology` constructor?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core?

Comment: No, but I already did that. It gives me a empty collection instead of a null. the thing is, it should return the collection of Projects since I add several Projects to that typology, it shouldn't return an empty collection.

Comment: Camilo, It's Entity Framework.

Comment: Did you add a `TopologyId` or anything to the Project so that the database actually stores the relationship? if you did so, you did not include it in the posted code.

Comment: Any difference with eager loading, e.g. `typology = dbContext.Typologies.Include(t => t.Projects).Where(t => t.Id == id).First();` ?

Comment: Camilo, yea I did. Actually, EntityFramework does that for me. I created the relationship, and in the Project table there's a column corresponding to the Typology Id which that project belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new `Project` to `Projects` collection of `typology` object. Something like this.

```
Typology typology = dbContext.Typologies.Where(t => t.Id == projectDTO.TypologyId).First();
            //projectContext.Typology = typology;

//dbContext.Projects.Add(projectContext);
typology.Projects.Add(new Project() {...});
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Still returning an empty collection.

Comment: Did you define `[ForeignKey]` in `Project` model?

Comment: I'm using the Fluent API to create the relationship, I don't need to. When I do `.HasRequired<Typology>(p => p.Typology)` the foreign key is created.

Comment: Do projects have not-null `typologyId` in DB?

Comment: Yea, by doing `.HasRequired` the entity is forced to not allow null entries, otherwise it'll raise an exception.

Comment: The last resort. Use `Include` in your `linq`.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

I just needed to change this line to my db context's constructor:

`Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;`

Since it was marked as `false` before.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that when i was querying model i forgot to add the *.Include(d => d.Projects)*.

Of course i am not the original poster so i replace the Projects to be the collection i was interested in.

```
var projects = await _dbContext.Typologies.Where(t => t.Id == projectDTO.TypologyId).Include('p => p.Projects').First()
```